# Can I insert a function inside a pthread_mutex_lock and unlock statements?

Tags: c, mutex

Let's suppose I want to set atomic instructions into a function.

I declared

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

as a global variable.

Instead of:

```
int main() {
     myFoo();
     ...
}

void myFoo() {
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     myGlobal++;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

can I do:

```
int main() {
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     myFoo();
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
     ...
}

void myFoo() {
     myGlobal++;
}
```

So that every instructions in `myFoo` become atomic?

Comment: no, not atomic. But access to`myFoo` will be synchronized. it is the case in the first code too.

Comment: It's not a good idea to call any function at all within mutex locks. Minimize the code there as much as possible. Ideally it should just read/write to the protected data to/from a local variable, then release the lock.

Comment: @Lundin it is not the interrupt routine. The resource locked can be anything - for example river lock. Then mutex will be kept for many minutes.

Comment: @P__J__ If you are fine with the other thread waiting while you process overhead code, then by all means.

Comment: @Lundin if you know that something may take longer you have always `...try` functions.

Comment: @P__J__ If `while(pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex)) twiddle_thumbs();` is meaningful, then yes. But if the other thread has nothing to do until gaining access to the mutex, then you are just creating a needlessly slow program.

Answer (score 4):

In first example, you are protecting `myGlobal` and in 2nd you are protecting `myFoo`. Your code works as you expect (if you call it everywhere between lock/unlock), but you need to use terms correctly or its meaning will be wrong.

No it will not be **atomic**, but access to `myFoo` will be synchronized, meaning no other thread can access that part code when a another thread is using it.

**Atomic** operation term normally is used showing that an instruction is run without any interruption (sometimes considered lock-free). For example, C11's [`atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_flag) provides such functionality. On the other hand, mutex is for creating [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). You can protect a part of your code from simultaneous access from different threads. These 2 terms are not similar.

**Side note:**

Only `atomic_` type that is guaranteed to be really atomic and lock-free is `atomic_flag` is both C and C++. Other ones such as `atomic_int` may be implemented using synchronization method and is not lock-free.

Comment: `std::atomic_flag`? It's a C question:)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the term atomic is not really correct but I guess the question is more about whether the two code snippets will behave the same.

If `myFoo` is **only** called between lock/unlock, the answer is yes, they are the same.

However, in the second case you have lost protection of `myFoo`. Another thread could call `myFoo` without calling lock first which would cause problems.

**So the second example is bad as it opens up for more mistakes. Stick to the first one, i.e. keep the lock/unlock inside the function**.

Also notice:

Since `myGlobal` is a global variable, you can't make sure that the threads do not access it directly. There are several ways to avoid that. The example below shows a single function with a static variable. The function can be used to receive the static variable and do an increment if desired.

```
int myFoo(int doIncrement) 
{
     static int myStatic = 0;
     int result;
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
     if (doIncrement) myStatic++;
     result = myStatic;
     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
     return result;
}
```

Now the variable `myStatic` is hidden from all the threads and can only be accessed through `myFoo`.

```
int x = myFoo(1);  // Increment and read
int y = myFoo(0);  // Read only
```

Comment: same about method one. Another thread may just `myGlobal++;` without worrying about mutrex-es.  If app is badly written nothing can protect you.

Comment: @P__J__ True. I updated the answer to cover that as well.